# A proof required for this identity

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-identities, elementary-proofs

Experiments support the below identity.

> **Question.** Is this true? Combinatorial proof preferred if possible.
>   $$\sum_{m=0}^n\binom{n-\frac13}m\binom{n+\frac13}{n-m}(1+6m-3n)^{2n+1}
> =\left(\frac43\right)^n\frac{(3n+1)!}{n!}.$$

In View of MTyson's suggestion (see below), a generalized question can be asked:

> **Question.** Is this true? Combinatorial proof preferred if possible.
>   $$\sum_{m=0}^n\binom{n-y}m\binom{n+y}{n-m}(y+2m-n)^{2n+1}
> =y\prod_{k=1}^n4(k^2-y^2).$$

Comment: Where does it come from?  Is the $m = n$ summand just equal to $0$?  (I guess one should interpret the binomial coefficients in general as ratios of gamma functions.)

Comment: Yes, treat as gamma functions. It came out of some work with determinants which is a long story to state here.

Comment: Why should the $m=n$ summand be $0$ ?

Comment: No need for gamma functions.  If $t$ is a nonnegative integer, $\binom st$ is defined as $s(s-1)\cdots(s-t+1)/t!$.  I checked the formula for $0\le n\le 300$.  Maple 2018 can't do the general sum.

Comment: If $m=n$ then the binomial equals $1$.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay: Thanks for re-checking. Your interpretation is right too.

Comment: If $m = n$ then the first binomial is $\binom{m - 1/3}m$, which I thought vanished.  @BrendanMcKay's comment clearly shows my error.

Comment: More generally, it seems that for $s(n)=\sum_{m=0}^n\binom{n-1/x}m\binom{n+1/x}{n-m}(1+2xm-xn)^{2n+1}$, $s(n)/s(n-1)=4(nx+1)(nx-1)$.

Comment: It's easy to show by canceling terms that the $s(n)$ in my previous comment has roots $\pm 1/k$ for $n\ge k$. Therefore it suffices to show that $s(n)$ is a degree $2n$ polynomial with the right leading or constant coefficient.

Comment: For $x=2$ and $x=4$ the oeis has interpretations http://oeis.org/A000909 and http://oeis.org/A009564 respectively.

Comment: The factor in the generalization should be $(y+2m-n)$, not $(y+6m-3n)$.

Comment: Your polynomial equals $\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}x^{2n+1-k}\binom{2n+1}k\sum_{m=0}^n\binom{n-x}m\binom{n+x}{n-m}(m-(n-m))^k$, so it suffices to show that the a priori degree $\le n$ polynomial $\sum_{i+j=n}\binom{n-x}i\binom{n+x}j(i-j)^k$ is only degree $k$ and has leading coefficient $2^k\binom{2n-k}{n-k}$. Note that at $k=0$ this is a (surprising) consequence of Chu-Vandermonde.

Comment: One can write the left hand side in a more symmetric way, albeit with a more awkward summation: $\sum_{k=-n\dots n, k=n\pmod 2} \binom{n-y}{(n-k)/2}\binom{n+y}{(n+k)/2}(y-k)^{2n+1}$

Comment: At the risk of stating the very obvious: the right hand side counts injective functions from $[2n+1]$ to $[x+n]$, where each value has one of $2$ colours (apart from an overall factor $2$).  This is not so bad, because the factor $(x+2m-n)^{2n+1}$ in the sum counts all functions from $[2n+1]$ to $[x+2m-n]$.

Comment: For the generalized eq. see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/262392/prod-kx-pm-k-in-binomial-basis

Comment: @MTyson I posted the proof of one half of the claim you wanted but then discovered that esg gave a reference to the full solution in the comments. :-) I'll still leave it there though it is not of much interest now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**"show that the a priori degree $\le n$ polynomial $\sum_{i+j=n}{n−x\choose i}{n+x\choose j}(i−j)^k$ is only degree $k$".**

That is fairly obvious when $k<2n+1$ because it suffices to check it for integer $x\in\{-n,\dots,n\}$. We will just show that for every $a,b\ge 0$ with $a+b\le k$, the sum $\sum_{i+j=n}{n−x\choose i}{n+x\choose j}{i\choose a}{j\choose b}$ is a polynomial of degree $\le a+b$ in $x$. When $|x|\le n$, this sum has a simple combinatorial meaning: choose some $n$ balls out of $2n$ ($i$ out of first $n-x$, $j$ out of last $n+x$) and color $a$ in the first group red and $b$ in the last group blue. But we can then compute it as ${n-x\choose a}{n+x\choose b}{2n-a-b\choose n-a-b}$ (choose colored balls first and add the remaining ones afterwards).

That the leading coefficient is right is not immediately obvious to me but, perhaps, someone can see it too.